# Swift performSegue going to Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, segue

I am trying to perform a Segue between two UI Views I have correctly typed the identifier for the segue as can be seen [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xj0Xh.png)

This is my function, with the same identifier "no" but when the button is clicked in the simulator it simply shows [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCgBg.png) (It looks like it is showing the stack in bottom left?)

```
 func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
    if control == view.rightCalloutAccessoryView {
         performSegue(withIdentifier: "no", sender:self)
    }
}
```

I have attached my full code incase further analysis is needed. Thanks for your help.

View Controller:
    import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet weak var MapView: MKMapView!
let manager = CLLocationManager()

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    //let location = locations[0]


    //let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.02, 0.02)

    //let myLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)


}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // tracking user's location
    manager.delegate = self
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    manager.startUpdatingLocation()

    // Setting up Map
    let distanceSpan:CLLocationDegrees = 2000
    MapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-39.0556253, 174.0752278), distanceSpan, distanceSpan), animated: true)
    MapView.showsUserLocation = true
    MapView.delegate = self

// artwork on map
    let windwandcoord: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-39.055961,174.072288)
    let artworkPin = Artwork(title:"Wind Wand",locationName:"Majestic",discipline:"Statue",
                             coordinate:windwandcoord)
    MapView.addAnnotation(artworkPin)
}


func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?
{
    if annotation is MKUserLocation {return nil}

    let reuseId = "pin"

    var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView
    if pinView == nil {
        pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
        pinView!.canShowCallout = true
        pinView!.animatesDrop = true
        pinView!.calloutOffset = CGPoint(x: -5, y: 5)
        let calloutButton = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
        pinView!.rightCalloutAccessoryView = calloutButton
        pinView!.sizeToFit()
    }
    else {
        pinView!.annotation = annotation
    }


    return pinView
}



func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
    if control == view.rightCalloutAccessoryView {
         performSegue(withIdentifier: "no", sender:self)
    }
}


}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: "it simply shows This" It's paused at a breakpoint. You put the breakpoint there. What's the problem?

Comment: I'm not putting the breakpoint, when the button is pressed the screen jumps to this. EDIT: Have updated image to try make it more clear.

Comment: You did put the breakpoint! I can _see_ it in the screen shot! That is what the blue bar in the gutter is, to the left of the green arrow on that line.

Comment: Uh no I am not putting the breakpoint in, it is doing it automatically when I press the button...

Comment: It isn't "doing it automatically". You put it there by clicking in the gutter (probably by accident, but you _did_ it). Therefore Xcode pauses when we reach it. Learn more about Xcode before you use it.

Comment: @T.Kearsley Just click and drag on the breakpoint to delete it. Or you can right click and choose delete breakpoint. Your app should run fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the solid blue bar in the gutter in your screen shot?

[image]

It is a *breakpoint*. When the path of execution reaches a breakpoint that is active (solid blue like this), we *pause* there. That is what a breakpoint is *for*.

If you don't want that to happen, drag the breakpoint *out* of the gutter.

Comment: Wow I feel like such an idiot! You were completely right! sorry really new to this didn't even realise I had done it! Thanks alot!

Comment: Next time please try listening more and arguing less.