# breakpoint 1.1 in prepare for segue function (swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, segue, xcode8

I have this breakpoint 1.1 with (if( segue.identifier == "MonthSegue" )) when i am trying to simulate my program!!
 I do not know what is the error! please if any one can help with this issue ...

[image: show breakpoint in Xcode]

```
  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if( segue.identifier == "MonthSegue" ) {
        let selectedRow = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row

        if let dest = segue.destination as? DaysTVC {
            dest.title = monthDataSet[selectedRow!]
            dest.monthNumber = selectedRow! + 1
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It looks like you're hitting the breakpoint set on line 31.  Delete that.  Control click on it and select delete.

Comment: @vacawama: I think what he means is that the breakpoint is generated automatically. XCode tends to do that if there is an error.

Comment: Exactly the same as http://stackoverflow.com/a/40499745/341994

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've accidentally set a breakpoint on line 31 of your code. Click on the blue arrow and drag it out of the gutter to delete it.

Comment: No need for such a clumsy approach: all he has to do is drag the breakpoint right out of the gutter. Or even just click it once to disable it.

Comment: Thanks @matt.  I changed the answer and up voted yours.